# BigQuery/SQL: If value is NULL, then (value != 'some string') returns false

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This query returns only the first line. But `NULL` is not equal to `"anything"`, why on earth would it return `FALSE`? Is this some kind of bug? This logic seems counterintuitive.

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT 'something' AS key
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL AS key
)

SELECT * FROM sample WHERE key != 'anything'
```

Comment: [`where` clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#where_clause): *Only rows whose bool_expression evaluates to TRUE are included. Rows whose bool_expression evaluates to NULL or FALSE are discarded.* [Operators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators): *Unless otherwise specified, all operators return NULL when one of the operands is NULL.*

Comment: yes, I figured this. My question is why `NULL != 'string'` is not `TRUE`?

Comment: I've updated my comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified, all operators return NULL when one of the operands is NULL

So, `NULL != 'string'` returns `NULL`, which is obviously not a `TRUE` (nor `FALSE`) and thus being excluded from output

You can see it by yourself, by running

```
SELECT *, key != 'anything' 
FROM sample
```

That is why you should use `IFNULL(key, '') != 'anything'`

You can see difference by running

```
SELECT *, key != 'anything', ifnull(key, '') != 'anything' 
FROM sample
```

P.S. You can see more about BigQuery [Operators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#array_subscript_operator)

> What's the benefit of having this kind of logic? Why NULL != 'anything' is not TRUE?

The SQL null value basically means “could be anything”. It is therefore impossible to tell whether a comparison to null is true or false. This logic is an integral part of Core SQL and it is followed by pretty much every SQL database

Think of null as a missed/absent data the value of which can be anything, thus result of comparison (or other operations) is unknown, which is what null is

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why is it designed this way? What's the benefit of having this kind of logic? Why `NULL != 'anything'` is not `TRUE`?

Comment: The SQL null value basically means “could be anything”. It is therefore impossible to tell whether a comparison to null is true or false. This logic is an integral part of Core SQL and it is followed by pretty much every SQL database

Comment: Think of `null` as a missed/absent data the value of which can be anything, thus result of comparison (or other operations) is unknown, which is what `null` is

Comment: @stkvtflw It is a standard convention in SQL: `null` is neither equal nor not equal to anything (including `null`)

Comment: @stkvtflw - if answer helped please accept it and vote it up if not yet :o)

Answer (score 1):

When you work with `Null` Value Then use `ISNULL` to setup you want to do. it's not bug.

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT 'something' AS [key]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL AS [key]
)

SELECT * FROM sample WHERE ISNULL([key],'') != 'anything'
```

Comment: thank you. But why is this a thing? NULL is not equal to any NOT NULL value.

Comment: A field with a NULL value is a field with no value. It is very important to understand that a NULL value is different than a zero value or a field that contains spaces.